# The language of the file referenced by the 'CodeFile' attribute does not match the language specified by the 'Language' attribute in the current file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When trying to edit a `aspx` page in Visual Studio i get the error:

> The language of the file referenced by the 'CodeFile' attribute does not match the language specified by the 'Language' attribute in the current file.

What's the problem?

**DocumentSearch.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
       AutoEventWireup="true" 
       CodeFile="DocumentSearch.aspx.cs" 
       Inherits="DocumentSearch" 
       Title="@Pepsi" %>
...
```

`C#` looks like it matches `.cs` to me.

**DocumentSearch.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class DocumentSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   ...
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You used `C#` and not `VB.net` in your `.cs` file, right? Can you also show us your `web.config` file? Speicifically, the `<system.codedom><compilers>` section

Comment: There is no `<system.codedom>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem. It's that [The Visual Studio language support for C# has not been installed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/477297/the-visual-studio-language-support-for-c-has-not-been-installed-code-editing-intellisense-will-not-be-available-markup-intellisense-for-server-controls-may-not-work).

The error message i **was** getting was misleading. The problem was that Visual Studio did not **have** C# installed - not that there was any mismatch. The reason C# was not installed is because i ran the wrong version of Visual Studio.

From the start menu i ran:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
```

when i should have ran

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
```

The problem, of course, is that the former isn't really Visual Studio. It's actually:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode)
```

Which is why C# wasn't available.